# file still showing up in github despite being added to gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following file structure and seem to be doing something wrong with handling the gitignore. I am trying to make sure variable.js is not pushed but despite it being listed under gitignore, it is still showing up on github. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide file/folder name you want to ignore.   In your case `variable.js` - it will ignore every file in your project that is `variable.js`.
If you only want to ignore file in root folder, add `/variable.js` to gitignore

edit: try to delete (move) file then commit changes. this should do the trick

Comment: That didn't seem to help. Also I tried git rm --cached varibale.js and it told me it didnt match any of the file names

Comment: show content of your `.gitignore`

Comment: That's what the picture i posted is.

Comment: @TNT928 Did you find a solution to it? I have a folder that I have put in gitignore but files inside it always show up anyway.